# How to fix filter button

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, user-interface

I am a newbie to html and spring boot, I am trying to filter and search within books in a list by author , description.. but my button does not seem to be funcrional, could you please help ?

Here s the code from the controller:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/filter", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public String filterBooks (Model model, @RequestParam(name = "author", required = false) String author,
    @RequestParam(name = "title", required = false) String title,
    @RequestParam(name = "description", required = false) String description,
    @RequestParam(name = "publishedDate", required = false) String publishedDate){
        List<Book> filterBooks = bookService.filterBooks(author, title, description, publishedDate);
        model.addAttribute("filterBooks", filterBooks);
        // return bookService.filterBooks(author, title, description, publishedDate);
        return"filter";
    }
```

and this is from the book service impl:

```
public List<Book> filterBooks(String author, String title, String description, String publishedDate) {
    List<Book> filteredBooks = new ArrayList<>();
    if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(books)) {
        filteredBooks.addAll(books.stream()
                .filter(book -> filterByAuthor(book, author) && filterByTitle(book, title)
                        && filterByDesc(book, description) && filterByPublishDate(book, publishedDate))
                .collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }
    return filteredBooks;
}

private boolean filterByAuthor(Book book, String author) {
    return StringUtils.isEmpty(author) ? Boolean.TRUE : book.getAuthor().equalsIgnoreCase(author);
}

private boolean filterByTitle(Book book, String title) {
    return StringUtils.isEmpty(title) ? Boolean.TRUE : book.getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase(title);
}

private boolean filterByDesc(Book book, String description) {
    return StringUtils.isEmpty(description) ? Boolean.TRUE : book.getDescription().equalsIgnoreCase(description);
}

private boolean filterByPublishDate(Book book, String publishDate) {
    return StringUtils.isEmpty(publishDate) ? Boolean.TRUE : book.getPublish_date().equalsIgnoreCase(publishDate);
}
```

and here is my filter html with the button search that is not working: https://wtools.io/paste-code/b5hg

Once the button is clicked the book should be selected from the available books list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why are you writing this much of codes
Solution:

> Try to implement CRUD operations with the help of JPA
> from crud operations you can use find by method and implement it .. its simplest approach